# Admin controller not working in Magento

Tags: magento

I've used a yeoman generator to build a Magento Module skeleton.

I can access the frontend module simply with:
http://prueba.com/index.php/prueba/index

But I can't make it work the admin. These are my files:

**/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<config>

        <menu>
            <prueba>
                <title>My Tab</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                     <action>adminhtml/prueba/index</action>
            </prueba>        
        </menu>
    </config>
```

**/controllers/adminhtml/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Index Adminhtml Controller
 *
 */
class Altimea_Prueba_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    /**
     * Index Action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

**/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Altimea_Prueba>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Altimea_Prueba>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <altimeaprueba>
                <class>Altimea_Prueba_Model</class>
            </altimeaprueba>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <altimeaprueba>
                <class>Altimea_Prueba_Block</class>
            </altimeaprueba>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <altimeaprueba>
                <class>Altimea_Prueba_Helper</class>
            </altimeaprueba>
        </helpers>

        <resources>
            <altimeaprueba_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Altimea_Prueba</module>
                    <class>Altimea_Prueba_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </altimeaprueba_setup>
        </resources>

    </global>

    <frontend>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <altimeaprueba>
                    <file>altimeaprueba.xml</file>
                </altimeaprueba>
            </updates>
        </layout>


        <routers>
            <altimeaprueba>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Altimea_Prueba</module>
                    <frontName>prueba</frontName>
                </args>
            </altimeaprueba>
        </routers>

    </frontend>


    <adminhtml>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <altimeaprueba>
                    <file>altimeaprueba.xml</file>
                </altimeaprueba>
            </updates>
        </layout>

    </adminhtml>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <altimeaprueba>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Altimea_Prueba</module>
                    <frontName>prueba</frontName>
                </args>
            </altimeaprueba>
        </routers>
    </admin>


</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

When create a magento admin module you can create it in one of two ways. Since you have both a front and backend controller try changing your admin route to `<frontname>admin_prueba</frontname>` then try  http://prueba.com/index.php/admin_prueba/index

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <menu1 translate="title" module="customlist">
            <title>ActiveCodeline SampleModule1</title>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem1 module="SampleModule1">
                    <title>Menu item 1</title>
                    <action>{{customlist}}/index</action>
                </menuitem1>


<admin>
    <routers>
        <samplemodule1>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>ActiveCodeline_SampleModule1</module>
                <frontname>admin_customlist</frontname>
            </args>
        </samplemodule1>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

or

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <menu1 translate="title" module="customlist">
            <title>ActiveCodeline SampleModule1</title>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem1 module="SampleModule1">
                    <title>Menu item 1</title>
                    <action>{{adminhtml/customlist}}/index</action>
                </menuitem1>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_CustomList before="Mage_Adminhtml">Foo_Bar_Adminhtml</Company_CustomList>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add this in config.xml

```
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
            <modules>
                <altimea_prueba after="Mage_Adminhtml">Altimea_Prueba_Adminhtml</altimea_prueba>
            </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Still doesn't load the controller having  that in config.xml

Comment: added <use>admin</use> in answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `config.xml`, change this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <altimeaprueba>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Altimea_Prueba</module>
                <frontName>prueba</frontName>
            </args>
        </altimeaprueba>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <altimea_prueba>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Altimea_Prueba</module>
                <frontName>prueba</frontName>
            </args>
        </altimea_prueba>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

If you want to see your "hello" printed out, in `IndexController.php`, add `exit();` after your `echo "hello";`

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference
It took me ages to figure out that

`<args>
    <modules>
        <myrandomtag before="Mage_Adminhtml">
            My_Module_Adminhtml
        </myrandomtag>
    </modules>
</args>`

IS NOT SAME AS

`<args>
    <modules>
        <myrandomtag before="Mage_Adminhtml">My_Module_Adminhtml</myrandomtag>
    </modules>
</args>`

So there should be no space or new line inside your random tag